# How to send MD5 hash of empty byte array?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web

I need to send a request from PHP to a C# WEB API.
As part of the authentication it requires an MD5 hash of an empty byte array.

**How can I generate an MD5 hash of an empty byte array on PHP?**
I would do it like this in C#.

```
byte[] Content = new byte[0];
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
  return md5.ComputeHash(content);
}
```

Comment: md5('') - is it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many way:

```
$hash = md5(null, true);
// or
$hash = md5('', true);
// or
$hash = md5(false, true);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am further converting the hashed value to base64 string.  
However the values produced by c# code and PHP don't match.  
PHP Code: 
`base64_encode(md5(null))`  
c# code:  
`byte[] Content = new byte[0]; 
 using (var md5 = MD5.Create()) 
    { 
       return Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(content)); 
    }`

Comment: PHP [md5](http://php.net/md5) produces a hex string, so I edited the answer with the `raw_output` set to TRUE. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/557925/how-can-zero-byte-files-generate-a-hash-value

If you can't compute it in PHP, then just use a constant and, for empty array, use that hash value.